# I cannot run any metal compute shader in my phone

Tags: metal

I am trying to run my metal program on my iPhone SE.

I tried many numbers for threadsPerThreadGroup and threadsPerGrid sizes and all of them gave me this error: `` TLValidateFeatureSupport:3539: failed assertion `Dispatch Threads with Non-Uniform Threadgroup Size is only supported on MTLGPUFamilyApple4 and later.' ``

Here is my code.

```
var threadsPerThreadGroup: MTLSize
var threadsPerGrid: MTLSize

computeCommandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(updateShader)

let w = updateShader.threadExecutionWidth

threadsPerThreadGroup = MTLSize(width: w, height: 1, depth: 1)
threadsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: Int(constants.bufferLength), height: 1, depth: 1)

if(frames % 2 == 0) {
    computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer1, offset: 0, index: 0)
    computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer2, offset: 0, index: 1)
} else {
    computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer2, offset: 0, index: 0)
    computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer1, offset: 0, index: 1)
}

 computeCommandEncoder.setBytes(&constants, length: MemoryLayout<MyConstants>.stride, index: 2)

computeCommandEncoder.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadGroup)

frames += 1
```

I am using iOS 13.4 and XCode 11.4.

threadExecutionWidth evaluates to 32 and constants.bufferLength is 512.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcomputecommandencoder/2866532-dispatchthreads

Comment: I think that 512, 1, 1 threadgrid and 32, 1, 1 threadgroups divide evenly, but XCode doesn't. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Per the documentation, you can't use that method if your device doesn't support non-uniform threadgroups _even if the threadgroup size(s) implied by your use of the method are uniform_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Use [dispatchThreads] only if the device supports non-uniform threadgroup sizes.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcomputecommandencoder/2866532-dispatchthreads)

That is not worded as clearly as it could be. It means that `dispatchThreads` *does not work* on pre-A11 GPUs.

If you want a solution that works on all devices, you have to calculate how many threadgroups go into a grid yourself, and use [dispatchThreadgroups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcomputecommandencoder/1443138-dispatchthreadgroups).

If you want to have both methods in your code, you can [detect the device's feature set at runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/detecting_gpu_features_and_metal_software_versions).